Maui Barometer reading on IOS crashes app
Part of my app is trying to read Barometric pressure if the sensor is available. The code works fine on Android but crashes the app on IOS. My iphone is has IOS 17.4. Under platform specific Microsoft talks about IOS Barometer uses the CMAltimeter for the measurement which possibly requires permissions being set.
In the Info.plist I have added the tag which I found in another forum.
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needed for Barometer reading</string>

The relavent code in my NavigationViewModel that causes the crash is as follows:
    if (Barometer.Default.IsSupported)
    {
        try
        { 
        Barometer.Default.ReadingChanged += Barometer_ReadingChanged;
        Barometer.Default.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Barometer through an error
            MyMessage = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        BarometerLabel = "NC";
    }

If all good it points to this routine:
private void Barometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, BarometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update UI Label with barometer state
    Bar1 = $"Barometer: {e.Reading}";
    BarometerLabel = Bar1.Substring(35, 4) + " mBar";
}

Frustratingly the catch does not catch an error and the tag in info.plist does not generate a user action.
Anyone got any ideas?

What do the logs show?  Have you tried using any crash logging tools?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to determine which specific line causes the crash?

The line Barometer.Default.Start(SensorSpeed.UI); causes the crash. No exception message is reported.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20930

This is an existing bug in github:iOS 17.4, Barometer.Default.Start hangs indefinately
This problem currently exists in iOS 17.4, and the issue link indicates that versions 17.5 and 17.4 minor versions have been released now.
So as the work around, you can prompt the user to update the iOS version and turn on the Motion & Fitness permission in your code:
        private async Task InitBarometer()
        {
            try
            {
#if IOS
                var version = DeviceInfo.Current.Version;
                if (version.Major == 17 && version.Minor == 4)
                {
                    _barometerDisabledReason = "Barometer is disabled for iOS 17.4. Update to iOS 17.5 to enable.";
                    throw new Exception(_barometerDisabledReason);
                }
                var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Sensors>();
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    _barometerDisabledReason = "Barometer is disabled. Please grant permission to 'Motion & Fitness' to enable.";
                    throw new Exception(_barometerDisabledReason);
                }
#endif

                _isBarometerEnabled = Barometer.Default.IsSupported;
                if (_isBarometerEnabled)
                {
                    Barometer.Default.ReadingChanged += Barometer_ReadingChanged;
                    Barometer.Default.Start(SensorSpeed.Default);
                }
            }
            catch
            {                
                _isBarometerEnabled = false;
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

